# Looping through 2 folders to perform extract by mask in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster

I am trying to perform the extract by mask function on rasters stored in workspace1 using the rasters stored in works. Pairs of rasters have the same name.

```
outdir="E:\output"
workspace1="E:\workspace1"
arcpy.env.workspace=workspace1
inras_list=arcpy.ListRasters("*",".tif")

workspace2="E:\workspace2"
for inras in inras_list:
    rasx=arcpy.sa.Raster(inras)
    rasy=arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(workspace2, inras))
    inras_extent=rasx.extent
    print inras_extent
    maskras_extent=rasy.extent
    print maskras_extent
    out_extract= arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(rasx,rasy)
    outname = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.basename(rasx).split(".")[0] + 
    "_opporwithX.tif")
    out_extract.save(outname)
```

The code works with no errors, but I see no outputs.

What is wrong with the code above and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you get any outputs for your print statements? Are you running this in CMD or by ArcGIS python console? Have you got a spatial analyst license? (you should, otherwise you'd get a 'license not initialized' error). I see no glaring errors in your code *except* your outname.. you're trying to split a **raster** object with **a string operation**, try os.path.join(outdir,os.path.splitext(inras)[0] +  "_opporwithX.tif") and see if that helps. You could also set your output extent to rasy arcpy.env.extent = rasy prior to the extract to ensure the output is shrunk to the mask extent.

Comment: Try printing `inras_list` before iterating it.  Maybe it is empty.  Maybe it has values that you were not expecting.

Comment: Both of you are correct and thank you! The inras_list was empty so I changed the line to inras_list=arcpy.ListRasters(). And I changed the outname as per @MichaelStimson comment